# Is there a simple way to write code if (mWiFiDef.isChecked) {aMutableList.add(mWiFiDef)} in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

At present, I have to write a full code for `if (mBluetoothDef.isChecked) { aMutableList.add(mBluetoothDef) }`.

I guess that maybe there is a simple way to do that in Kotlin. How can I do?

```
var aMutableList= mutableListOf<DeviceDef>()

var mBluetoothDef=BluetoothHelper(mContext).getBluetooth()
var mWiFiDef= WiFiHelper(mContext).getWiFi()

if (mBluetoothDef.isChecked) { aMutableList.add(mBluetoothDef) } // Simple way?
if (mWiFiDef.isChecked) {aMutableList.add(mWiFiDef)}  //Simple way?


interface DeviceDef

data class BluetoothDef(
        val isChecked: Boolean = true,
        val status: Boolean = false
) : DeviceDef

data class WiFiDef(
        val isChecked: Boolean = true,
        val name: String,
        val status: Boolean = false
) : DeviceDef
```

Comment: The code looks rather simple to me. What is the problem?

Comment: Thanks! i hope I can most simple in Kotlin

Comment: Simple also means understandable. Everybody can understand this.

Answer (score -1):

Highly recommend to use when expressions if even couple of if's is required:

```
when {
    mBluetoothDef.isChecked -> aMutableList.add(mBluetoothDef)
    mWiFiDef.isChecked -> aMutableList.add(mWiFiDef)
    else -> {}
}
```

Comment: This code is not equivalent — multiple choice vs. single choice.

Comment: This comment is irrelevant — as there are few properties author want to check.

Comment: Your code can only add either wifi or bluetooth to the list. OP's code can add either or both of them. Your code, however demonstrative it may be, does something else than was intended.